# Spring REST-JWT-JavaScript navigate between secure pages

Tags: javascript, html, spring, rest, jwt

I have a Java Spring REST back-end (@RestController) and using as security option Json Web Tokens(no session). At the front-end I want to use JavaScript (jQuery to send requests to back-end), Html.
So after login I save a JWT in browser and send it back in header with every request I make to @RestController.

My question is: How to navigate between pages (that are accessible only for authenticated users) from js? How @RestController will work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The @RestController handle the requests containing a path (the path of the request is not necessary to be the same with the path(URL) from front-end)

Solution (if you have a front-end server): When you try to reach a front-end URL you make a call to the server-side; if the response status is 200 the page can be displayed(with the body of the response if you send information); if the response is not you will stay on the home page, or you can redirect the user to login page...

Also check this : http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-method-level/